# How do I clip a raster to the shape of a polygon (non rectangle)

Tags: raster, data, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, clip

I would like to clip a raster to follow the shape of a river, which has lots of meaders and bends. I have created a buffer for the river of 300m and was hoping to use this to clip the raster. However, the raster clips to a rectangle shape. Is there a way to change this? I am using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Clipping with an irregular polygon is a vector thing. What you want is to *mask* in a 1/nodata raster generated from your irregular polygon (`Con` can do the masking)

Comment: Thank you. This worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Use Extract by Mask.